# alert when multiple elements with the same class name have an added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need an alert to show up when all elements have had a class added to them

html

```
    <ul class="container">
    <li class="box"> </li>
    <li class="box"> </li>
    <li class="box"> </li>
    </ul>
```

jquery -

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.box').click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('Boxaddedclass');
          });
         });
```

After each box is clicked, a class of 'Boxaddedclass' is added to each list with the class of '.box'.

jquery -

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".box").click(function () {
            if($(".box").hasClass("Boxaddedclass")) {
             alert('all boxes have the added class')

              } 
            });
```

At the moment, after I click each individual Box class, an alert comes up each time, I need the alert to appear when all of them have the added class rather than individually. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".box.Boxaddedclass")` selector could be used to check `.box` elements also has `.Boxaddedclass` class.

Only using `$(".Boxaddedclass")` will not consider `.box` elements having `Boxaddedclass` class!

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('Boxaddedclass');
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var boxCount = $(".box").length;
  var addedBoxClass = $(".box.Boxaddedclass").length;
  if (boxCount === addedBoxClass) {
    alert("All boxes have added the class");
  } else {
    alert('Not yet!')
  }
});
```

```css
.Boxaddedclass {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="box">Content...</li>
  <li class="box">Content...</li>
  <li class="box">Content...</li>
</ul>
<div class="Boxaddedclass">Other content not having `box` class but `Boxaddedclass`</div>
<br>
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: Any particular reason this isnt a comment on my answer since you only added 4 characters to my solution?

Comment: @SterlingArcher — There could be many `.Boxaddedclass` elements in the DOM, OP is more concerned about `.box` element having specified class..

Comment: This gave the best explanation, and it worked perfectly after tinkering a little (I wish my example html was as simple as my example :) ) Appreciate the snippet too.

Comment: @jaystephens — I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 2):

Compare the number of elements classed `.box` with `.Boxaddedclass`

```
var boxCount = $(".box").length;
var addedBoxClass = $(".Boxaddedclass").length;
if (boxCount === addedBoxClass) {
    alert("All boxes have added the class"); //note that I don't support alert, you really should console.log it, or do something fancier
}
```